# Read excel columns as string even it contains numeric value without formatting using apache-poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I need help about an issue that try to reading excel values as it looks. Let me explain with example,

In excel my rows with first column (mixed with string values),

10,4
10,2
**11.5** //some columns using . notation
someString

When I try to read values using apache-poi
outputs: (it replaces "," with "." not wanted)
10.4
10.2
**11.5**
someString

it should give excatly same output. if it use ".", output should "10.4 if it use "," it should "10,4"

Even I format cells the column as text from excel, still get same output.
I don't want to use string replace because input might **be 10.4 with real dot.**

Here as example code I am using,

```
    Sheet firstSheet = excel.getSheetAt(0);
    for (Row s : firstSheet) {
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = s.iterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
            if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
            } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                String textValue = NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Notes:
Apache-poi version: 4.0
Java: 8.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the need is to get all cell values as string, then you should not get the cell values by `CellType`. Instead you should using `apache poi`'s [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). The `DataFormatter` can have set  a `Locale`. This `Locale` then determines using what decimal delimiters and thousands separators numeric values are shown.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Locale;

class GetDataFromExcelUsingDataFormatter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.GERMANY);
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
    System.out.println(cellValue);
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

This shows numeric values like `10.4` as `10,4` because of the German locale set.

The `Excel` file always contains numeric content in en_US locale form. So the content `10.4` will be stored as `10.4` if it is numeric. It is the `Excel` application then which transforms the content into other locale forms according to the locale of the operating system. That's why `apache poi`'s `DataFormatter` also needs locale settings.

A `Excel` workbook **either** has dot as decimal delimiter **or** it has comma as decimal delimiter. It cannot have both the same time. So if in the same `Excel` sheet one cell contains `10.4` and another cell contains `10,4` then one of both must be text. In same `Excel` sheet `10.4` and `10,4` cannot be numeric the same time. The `DataFormatter` hands over text content totally untouched. So if `10,4` is the numeric value, then `DataFormatter`formats it using the `Locale`. But the `10.4` then must be text and `DataFormatter` will hand over it untouched as `10.4`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, The issue not about Locale, I wrote but it was not highlighted sorry. 10.4 -> 10.4 and 10,4 -> 10,4   if it is dot output should be with dot, if it is comma output should with comma.

Comment: @Hakan Kara: A `Excel` workbook **either** has dot as decimal delimiter **or** it has comma as decimal delimiter. It cannot have both the same time. So if in the same `Excel` sheet one cell contains `10.4` and another cell contains `10,4` then one of both must be text. The `DataFormatter` hands over text content totally untouched. So my answer will work even for this case. My answer remains.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But here I want every cell value as string even it contains any valid numeric value. Thus, it should treat every value as string. What I see excel columns I want to get back same without any formatting application too.

Comment: @Hakan Kara: Have you even tried my code? It does exactly what you wants.

Comment: I have just tried and I got what I want. thank you so much.